# I want to make it so that when I click, the bullet on screen moves

Tags: c#, monogame

I am making a game where you play as a tank and need to shoot moving targets by clicking the left button. I cannot get the bullet to move.

```
private void drawShoot()
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(tankImg, tankRec, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.Draw(bulletImg, bulletRec, Color.White);
        
    }

private void tankShoot(GameTime gameTime)
    {
            if (mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && prevMouse.LeftButton != ButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                speed.Y = bulletDirY * (bulletSpeed * (float)(gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds));

                bulletPos.Y = bulletPos.Y - speed.Y;
                bulletRec.Y = (int)bulletPos.Y;
            }
    }
```

FYI these are both called when necessary. When I click left button, the bullet moves for like a millisecond, and I need to click it again to move it. If anyone could help me make it so that when I click left button once it keeps moving, that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: It's because you wrote the behaviour of bullets under the condition `(mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && prevMouse.LeftButton != ButtonState.Pressed)`, that's why it only moves when you pressed mouse button. The `left click and shoot` behaviour should be written in tank or player controller's script, while the `bullet movement` behaviour should be written in the bullet object's script. Maybe make it go straight forward in the bullet's `FixedUpdate`.

Comment: Wait just realized this ain't Unity... But the basic logic is the same. `Tank` and `Bullet` are different things, so you should write their logics separately.

Comment: @XiangWeiHuang looks like that's a start of a good answer! Mind to flesh it out as an answer post?

Answer (score 0):

Clicking the button initializes the shot, but you need to keep moving it. The way you have it, it just shoots once when the button is clicked, and then nothing else.

Your game runs on a game loop. Your game should have an `Update()` method (all MonoGame games should). Instead of doing the calculations in the `tankShoot()` method, set a flag instead, like this:

```
private void tankShoot(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if (mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && prevMouse.LeftButton != ButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        _bulletShot = true;
    }
}
```

Then in your `Update()` method, you can call your bullet class. If `_bulletShot` is true, it can calculate its new, current position. You'll have to take into account the game time as well. This isn't hard since `Update()` takes `GameTime` as a parameter:

```
public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
```

When the bullet hits something or goes offscreen, you can reset `_bulletShot` back to false.

This is just a simple example, but it should get the point across.